# Mensagem "301 Moved Permanently" começou a aparecer repentinamente

Tags: java, http, post, get, spring-mvc

Estou com duas aplicações que funcionavam perfeitamente, porém, sem que houvessem alterações no código, não funcionam mais.

De um lado, uma aplicação com um JSP fazendo uma chamada *POST* e passando dois parâmetros *hidden*:

```
<li>
 <form name="login" method="post" action="http://dominio.com/aplicacao/chamadaApp">
  <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="conteudo1">
  <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="conteudo2">
  <A href="javascript:login()" class="classe1"></A>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function login()
   {
    document.login.submit();
   }
  </script>
 </form>
</li>
```

Do outro lado, outra aplicação SpringMVC com o seguinte trecho de código, recebendo a solicitação acima:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/chamadaApp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(
      @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = false) String param1,
      @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = false) String param2,
      WebRequest request) {
 //código
}
```

Funcionava perfeitamente, porém, de uma hora pra outra, a aplicação SpringMVC começou a retornar o erro ***HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported***. Isso não faz sentido, pois tanto o HTML realiza uma chamada *POST* quanto a aplicação espera também receber uma chamada *POST*.

Investigando um pouco mais, descobri com o FIREBUG que ao realizar a chamadaApp, antes de mostrar o erro acima, é retornado o status: ***301 Moved Permanently***, o que me fez suspeitar de algum problema de infra, mas não faço ideia do que pode ser.

Alguém sabe o que esse erro significa e como resolvê-lo?

Answer (score 2):

Isso tem cara de um [proxy reverso](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_reverso) mal configurado, que está redirecionando as chamadas para o servidor web de forma incorreta.

Dado seu código HTML e o método do Spring Controller, mais a informação de que o sistema não foi modificado, não há motivos para achar que o problema está na aplicação.

Analise os logs de acesso do seu servidor de aplicação para ver que tipo de requisição o mesmo está recebendo.

Se está "saindo" um `POST` do Firefox e chegando um `GET` no servidor de aplicação, então você "matou" a charada e sabe que o problema está na configuração de infra.

Você também pode analisar o cabeçalho das requisições que chegam no servidor de aplicação procurando por [cabeçalhos de redirecionamento](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers), tais como:

- `X-Forwarded-For`
- `X-Forwarded-Host`
- `X-Forwarded-Server`

Comment: Problema resolvido: a chamada para a aplicação SpringMVC era realizada em http (não-segura) e o servidor redirecionava para https (segura) automaticamente. Nesse redirect, retornava o status 301. Por orientação do suporte de infra, alterei a chamada para que fosse realizada diretamente para https e passou a funcionar. Deu certo, mas infelizmente permanece a dúvida e talvez seja o que você suspeitou: algum problema no proxy reverso, mas não tenho como confirmar que seja realmente isso.

Comment: @dellasavia Fico feliz que tenha resolvido, mas realmente não tem como saber exatamente o que ocorreu. Provavelmente colocaram uma nova regra de redirecionamento na surdina, só que dificilmente o pessoal vai admitir.